# Decorator pattern with varying contract

Tags: java, design-patterns

In the decorator pattern, I'm confused about how to use a decorator method. I have learned that the decorator pattern is used to add functions to base-class. But I could call only the outermost decorator's method, so how should I use inner-decorator's method, if it not mentioned in interface. I'm not good at English, so I write code to demonstrate my question.

```
public class OrderSystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pancakes pancakes = new MixedPancakes();
        pancakes = new Ham(pancakes);
        ((Ham) pancakes).hamState(); // call hamState
        pancakes = new Egg(pancakes);
        ((Egg) pancakes).eggState();
        // i can't call hamState() there because it not belong to Egg

        Pancakes pancakes1 = new Ham(new Egg(new FlourPancakes()));
        // similarly, i can't use eggState() there.
        System.out.println("订单:" + pancakes1.getDescription());
        System.out.println("价格：" + pancakes1.cost());
    }
}

interface Pancakes {
    public abstract String getDescription();

    public abstract int cost();
}

abstract class Seasoning implements Pancakes {
    @Override
    public abstract String getDescription();
}

class Ham extends Seasoning {

    Pancakes pancakes;

    public Ham(Pancakes pancakes) {
        this.pancakes = pancakes;
    }

    @Override
    public int cost() {
        return pancakes.cost() + 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return pancakes.getDescription() + "+火腿";
    }

    public void hamState() {
        System.out.println("火腿切碎");
    }

}

class Egg extends Seasoning {

    Pancakes pancakes;

    public Egg(Pancakes pancakes) {
        this.pancakes = pancakes;
    }

    @Override
    public int cost() {
        return pancakes.cost() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return pancakes.getDescription() + "+鸡蛋";
    }

    public void eggState() {
        System.out.println("鸡蛋打碎");
    }
}

class MixedPancakes implements Pancakes {

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "五谷杂粮煎饼";
    }

    @Override
    public int cost() {
        return 6;
    }
}

class FlourPancakes implements Pancakes {

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "白面煎饼";
    }

    @Override
    public int cost() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

As I asked in annotation, when a decorator was wrapped with another, only the method that declared in interface (like `cost()` and `getDescription()`) will work, and the other method won't be called anymore. I thought if I create a soldier, if I use a gun decorate he will be `shoot()`--the gun's function. If I decorate him with sword tomorrow, he will not only could `shoot()` but also `cut()`--the sword's function. Can I achieve it with decorator pattern?
I'm sorry for any misunderstandings and thanks for your help.

Comment: The point of a decorator is not to add methods. It's to make the methods of the decorated object do something *more*, or *different*. The decorator is supposed to have the same type as the object being decorated. For example, a BufferedReader decorates another reader. Its read() method delegates to the decorated reader's read() method, but adds buffering on top.

Comment: @JBNizet, this should be an answer, not a comment, I think.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz That wouldn't answer the question.

Comment: @YuhangHan The method names `eggState` and `hamState` really don't make sense. What are these methods supposed to do? This would help to answer the question.

Comment: @CKing It's not necessary to answer the literal question if the question is misinformed and wrong like here (i.e. a misunderstanding of the decorator pattern). In my eyes a good answer solves a problem, even if it may not directly address the question that was asked.

Comment: @Kayaman It's true that the question is misinformed; however, a good answer to the question would be one that first explains why it is misinformed and then proceeds to explain an alternate approach to solve this problem. A design pattern can be extended/modified/dropped completely based on the situation. If we stick by textbook definitions of patterns, very little would be possible in the real world IMO.

Comment: @CKing JB Nizet correctly explained what is wrong with the asker's understanding of the decorator pattern, so it would make a decent answer. This is not a case of "textbook definition". It's a case of misunderstanding and then writing not working code based on that misunderstanding. It's the equivalent of asking "how can I get multiple instances of singleton". You wouldn't try to work around that, would you.

Comment: @Kayaman A *Singleton* by design can allow you to have multiple instances. Do read [this](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/179386/what-are-the-downsides-of-implementing-a-singleton-with-javas-enum) answer that does a good job in explaining the purpose of `getInstance`. Point being, patterns can be evolved/extended as per your needs. I agree with you that the comment would answer a part of the question, but it would create a wrong notion that a *pattern* is meant to be used as-is and you should not think about how to evolve it to suit your requirement.

Comment: @CKing A singleton with multiple instances is not a singleton. It's a multipleton, an object pool or something similar. In this question the problem was a misunderstanding. Stop trying to pretend it's something else and that it wouldn't make a good answer.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes. But it was once a *Singleton* but can now return multiple instances and you can call it a multipleton if you like. Point being, something that was designed as a singleton is now a multipleton. Something that started as a *Decorator* could be evolved into the requirement that the OP has. It might or not might not be called a *Decorator* any longer but it would answer the indirect question.

Comment: @Kayaman Not sure what you mean by that. I would still stick to saying that the comment only answers a part of the question (the direct part). People often talk about the [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem on this site. This could very well be a case where the OP is asking about the decorator pattern but what he really wants is a way to solve his design problem.

Comment: @CKing `hamState` means what the ham state when i add it into Pancakes ,  i can choice add a whole ham or ham pellet . if i want to know the state of ham , is it the only choice to add `getter` in interface

Comment: thanks for help, after saw your discussion , i know Decorate Pattern used to make method greater not the class . and if i need add new method , it is no good to use this pattern. am i right?

Comment: Your example with soldier might work with decorator if the Weapon (via composition) was decorated. They key is to find the right abstractions where it makes sense to encapsulate. Decorator is about encapsulation, which means you don't want or don't have access to the decorated objects.

Answer (score 1):

As people mentioned in comments in your question, the decorator pattern is not used exactly like that.

Using your soldier example, the decorator would work like this:

```
public abstract class Soldier {
    public abstract void attack();
}

public abstract class SoldierDecorator extends Soldier {

    protected Soldier soldier;

    public SoldierDecorator(Soldier soldier) {
        this.soldier = soldier;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract void attack();
}
```

and then

```
public class SoldierWithGun extends SoldierDecorator {

    public SoldierWithGun(Soldier soldier) {
        super(soldier);
    }

    @Override
    public void attack() {
        soldier.attack();
        shootWithTheGun();
    }

    private void shootWithTheGun() {
        System.out.println("Shooting with the gun...");
    }
}

public class SoldierWithSword extends SoldierDecorator {

    public SoldierWithSword(Soldier soldier) {
        super(soldier);
    }

    @Override
    public void attack() {
        soldier.attack();
        cutWithSword();
    }

    private void cutWithSword() {
        System.out.println("Cutting with the sword...");
    }
}
```

Passing your soldier from decorator to decorator would enhance their attack;

Now to add behavior/methods, you can use plain old inheritance.

You could add behavior by extending classes, BaseSoldier can walk but SoldierWithGun extends BaseSoldier, adds a method to shoot besides walking.

You can use interfaces to ensure that certain functionalities are available in classes that implement them.

It is not exactly "decorating" as you want, but I think this is the way to go for what you want to do.